# Evaluating ASPX Pages from custom httpHandlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httphandler

I have search everywhere for help and its starting to annoy me.

I am creating an Internal Tooling Website which stores Tools and their related information.

My vision is to have a web address (Http://website.local/Tool/ID)
Where ID is the ID of the Tool we want displayed.
My reasoning is then I can extend the functionality of the URL to allow for various other functions.

Currently I use a custom httpHandler which intercepts any URL which is in the 'Tool' Folder.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Tooling_Website.Tool
{
    public class ToolHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }


        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //The URL that would hit this handler is: http://{website}/Tool/{AN ID eg: http://{website}/Tool/PDINJ000500}
            //The idea is that what would be the page name is now the ID of the tool.
            //tool is an ASPX Page.
            tool tl = new tool();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htr = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(context.Response.Output);
            tl.RenderControl(htr);
            htr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I have a page inside the 'Tool' folder (Tool\tool.aspx) which I want my customer httpHandler to Render into the Response.

But this method doesn't work (It doesn't fail, just doesn't show anything) I can write the raw file to the response but obviously thats not my goal.

Thanks,

Oliver

Comment: Have you considered using ASP.NET MVC?  Seems like it would be a good fit for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Needs to be for .net 3.5, got a good example?

Comment: MVC2 works with .NET 3.5.  The http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ example is the canonical example.  Essentially, you'd want a standard TooController with an Index action that takes a specific tool id. You can add additional actions or parameters (or both) to extend the functionality.

Comment: Cool, I'll look into that, but for the time being I am still open to solutions that don't require additional libraries.

Comment: Another option, seeing as you can't use .net 4.0 (and webforms routing) is IIS url rewrite 2.0. http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: @OliverBaker understandable, but it sure looks like you're on the road to reinventing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you still want to use your custom approach, you can try to do the following in your *IHttpHandler* derived class:

```
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //NOTE: here you should implement your custom mapping
            string yourAspxFile = "~/Default.aspx";
            //Get compiled type by path
            Type type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(yourAspxFile);
            //create instance of the page
            Page page = (Page) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            //process request
            page.ProcessRequest(context);
        }
```